# Google map won't show After transferring android studio project from 1 pc to another

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest

Today i tried to copy android studio project which contains

```
class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener,MyDialogFragment.OnDialogFragmentInteractionListener
```

after coping project i also changed android.geo.API_KEY in manifest file but it can't affect anything.

Comment: You have to be more clear about what is your problem.

Comment: Have you Generate and Update sha-1 in google console of new pc ?

Comment: i already told  that i  done it so please read carefully before cooment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have changed operating system or pc itself, in that case you have to create new debug or release  key for google map based on that android studio or whatever IDE. Get a new `SHA` value in current system and create new `API` key.

Comment: did you regenerated your android api key in developer console ?

Answer (score 0):

I done it! by just replacing default.keyset file in .android folder with  default.keyset from 1st PC